# React page flickers when rendering component after authentication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, oauth

I have a `PrivateRoute` component that wraps other components which need authentication to access. `PrivateRoute` calls an API that checks for auth, and in the meantime, displays a `Loading` component before deciding whether or not to redirect if the user is authenticated or not.

When a user initially logs in via Google OAuth, I want to display `ComponentA` that is protected by `PrivateRoute`.

The ideal flow here would be:

User authenticates => redirect to `PrivateRoute` => `Loading` component renders while API call finishes => `ComponentA` is rendered as the user just authenticated

However, I'm getting something like:

User authenticates => `ComponentA` renders briefly => redirect to `PrivateRoute` => `Loading` component renders while API call finishes => `ComponentA` is rendered as the user just authenticated

This causes whatever is going to be rendered upon successful authentication (`ComponentA` in this case) to briefly be shown to the user, before they continue down the ideal flow. Has anyone run into a problem like this before? Thanks!

`PrivateRoute` code below:

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { isLoaded, isEmpty } from "react-redux-firebase";
import Loading from './Auth/Loading'
import get from "lodash/get";

const Private = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const auth = useSelector(state => state.firebase.auth)
  const pathname = get(rest, "location.state.from.pathname");
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => 
        isLoaded(auth) ? (
          !isEmpty(auth) ? (
            <Component {...props} {...rest} oldPath={pathname} />
          ) : (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: pathname || "/",
                state: { from: props.location },
              }}
            />
          )
        ) : (
          <Loading />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was redirecting to the `PrivateRoute` component using `window.location.pathname` instead of `history.push`, because the latter was causing an infinite rendering loop error with React. But, this time, using `history.push` didn't cause this error, and fixed the problem I had as well.